# How to fetch data from multiple tables if records exist or not

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables

**Category**

```
category_id int(11) auto increment PK
name varchar(100)
```

**Product**

```
category_id int(11) FK from increment 
product_id int(11) auto increment PK
Name varchar(100)
```

**Favourite**

```
favourite_id int(11) auto increment PK
product_id int(11) FK from product
user_id int(11) FK from user
```

I want data all product `name, category name, favourite = 1` if records exist in favourite table else 0 for particular user

Comment: Please add some input and out data to your question to get proper answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [LEFT JOIN](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/):

```
SELECT A.Name Product_Name, B.Name Category_Name 
FROM Product A LEFT JOIN Category B
ON A.category_id=B.category_id
LEFT JOIN Favourite C
ON A.product_id=C.product_id
WHERE favourite_id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
SELECT p.`name` , c.name AS categoryName  , IFNULL(f.user_id,0), IFNULL(f.product_id ,0)
FROM Category c INNER JOIN Product p 
ON c.category_id  = p.category_id 
LEFT JOIN Favourite f 
ON f.product_id =p.product_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `$user_id` for particular user

```
SELECT p.Name as product_name, c.Name as Category_name 
FROM Product p 
JOIN Category c ON p.category_id=c.category_id
JOIN Favourite f ON p.product_id=f.product_id
WHERE f.user_id= '$user_id';
```